# Exclude Js (vendor-core.js) file from particular view in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I want to disalbe vendor-core.js in myParticular view file.
I have included it in AppAsset.php.
but i do not need it in particular page as it is causing some serious issues.

My need is to remove vendor-core.js in particular view file. Other Js files will be loaded as it is.

vendor-core.js is needed in mostly views. but few are important views in which i do not want to include it.

Any help will highly appriciated.

thanks in advance..

Here is my AppAsset code

```
<?php

/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;


/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        //  'css/site.css',
        'css/vendor.min.css',
        'css/theme-core.min.css',
        'css/module-essentials.min.css',
        'css/module-layout.min.css',
        'css/module-sidebar.min.css',
        'css/module-sidebar-skins.min.css',
        'css/module-navbar.min.css',
        'css/module-media.min.css',
        'css/module-timeline.css',
        'css/module-chat.min.css',
        'css/module-charts.min.css',
        'css/module-maps.min.css',
        'css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css',
        'css/custom.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
      'js/vendor-core.js',
        'js/vendor-tables.min.js',
    //    'js/vendor-forms.min.js',
        'js/vendor-media.min.js',
        'js/vendor-charts-all.min.js',
        'js/vendor-maps.min.js',
        'js/vendor-tree.min.js',
        'js/vendor-nestable.min.js',
  //      'js/module-essentials.min.js',
   //     'js/module-layout.min.js',
        'js/module-sidebar.min.js',
        'js/module-media.min.js',
        'js/module-chat.min.js',
        'tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
        'js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',

    ];

//public $jsOptions =[
//    'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_READY
//];

}
```

Comment: @GAMITG : can u help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Init function in your AppAsset
and push css or your js on conditions according to controller id and/or action id

```
public function init()
{  
    if(\Yii::$app->controller->id == 'controllerid')
    {


        array_push($this->css,'css-path/file.css');

        array_push($this->js,  'js-path/file.js');
    }
}
```

And for the ease in your case you can unset the same from js array instead of push in above function and it will not load in that particular action

```
if(($key = array_search('js-path/file.js', $this->js)) !== false) {
                    unset($this->js[$key]);
   }
```